# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

Alright I'm getting the error from my username exists function.
This is the register function.

```
public function register($username, $upassword){
    if(!$this -> exists($username)) {
        $salt = $this->salt();
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $password = $this->md5($upassword, $salt);

        $SQL = $this -> db -> prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, salt, created_at) VALUES(:username, :password, :salt, :date)");
        $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password, ':salt' => $salt,':date' => $date));
    return TRUE;
  } else {
      return FALSE;
  }
}
```

The error seems to be coming from the prepare statement in this line.

```
public function exists($username){
       $SQL = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE `username` = :username");
       $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username ));
       $count = $SQL -> fetchcolumn(0);
       if($count > 0) {
           return TRUE;
       } else {
           return FALSE;
       }
   }
```

Getting the error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in functions.php on line 41

Which is the first line within the exist function?

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: What is `$this -> db`?

Comment: var $db;
    function _construct($db){
        $this -> db = $db;
    }

Comment: where is your db connection?

Comment: define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$db = new PDO('mysql: host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

Comment: that all are defined inside the class, right?

Comment: yes of course, I'm wondering why it's spitting this error, not a complete fix but more of a theory and I should be able to fix it myself.

Comment: I think it's variable scope issue, just try to add 'public' to your $db variable, or, include 'global $this->$db' inside each your function, before 'prepare' statement. good luck!

Comment: where do you define your $db? what is inside?

Answer (score 0):

exists() class doesn't 'see' your $this->db, try to debug it, if it really is referencing or can be used in exists() class

Comment: var $db;
    public function _construct($db){
        $this -> db = $db;
    }

define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$db = new PDO('mysql: host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

Comment: Exists($username) is a function within my user class.
`var $db; public function _construct($db){ $this -> db = $db; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to instantiate your class like this: `new ClassName($db)` then `$this->db` most likely isn't defined because you haven't actually defined a constructor for your class that does anything with `$this->db`.

`_construct($db)` should be `__construct($db)`

Assuming you wanted the constructor magic method.  All magic methods start with two underscores.